# Casting issues in C#

Tags: c#, oop

I have aprogram

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Generic
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            List<string> dd= Program.get();
        }

        public static IList<string> get()
        {
            List<string> str = new List<string>();
            return str;  
        }
    }
}
```

On executing above I am getting:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>'` to
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'`. An explicit conversion
>   exists
>        (are you missing a cast?).

Since,  List derives IList , this should't fail.
Then why C# is throwing this error?

Comment: `List<string>` is a subtype of `IList<string>` so the assignment is invalid.

Comment: Thanls @Lee with logic  List<string> str = new List<string>();
should also fails. But is does not.

Comment: That's not the same logic, it fails for the same reason `string s = new object();` won't compile. You can't assign an expression of some type to a variable of some subtype.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you can guarantee that all `List` objects are of type `IList`, you can't guarantee that all `IList` objects are of type `List`, since it could be an entirely different class that is implementing the interface. This means that in the line

```
List<string> dd= Program.get();
```

you are trying to tell the compiler that the `IList` is actually a `List`, but it doesn't know that. The `IList` could actually be derived from a different subclass not even related to `List`. You could do an explicit cast,

```
List<string> dd= (List<string>)Program.get();
```

but this could lead to runtime issues if it were ever possible for `Program.get()` to return something other than `List` which happened to implement `IList`.

It is much better to explicitly state the return type of `get()` as `List<string>` if you really need access to features only available in `List`, or to just declare the type of `dd` as `IList<string>` if the `IList` interface provides all of the methods you ever intend to call.

As an example, consider the following:

```
interface Foo {
    public void doSomething();
}

class Bar : Foo {
    public override void doSomething() {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}

class Baz : Foo {
    public override void doSomething() { 
        Console.WriteLine("Goodbye World!");
    }
}

class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Foo myFoo = getMyFoo();
        myFoo.doSomething();
    }

    static Random random = new Random();
    static Foo getMyFoo() {
        if (random.NextDouble() < 0.5){
            return new Bar();
        }
        else {
            return new Baz();
        }
    }
}
```

We can see that both `Bar` and `Baz` are of type `Foo`, but we are never guaranteed which type gets returned from `getMyFoo()`, only that it is of type `Foo`. We could try explicitly casting `myFoo` to one or the other, but we would generally fail at runtime because `Baz` is not of type `Bar` or vice versa.